How can I get head of branch with illegal characters in it
I know you can get the head of a branch directly using it's name (e.g. repo.heads.main).  Can you get the head of a branch that has illegal variable characters (e.g. feature-generate-events) directly or do I have to iterate to get it?  The hyphens are illegal (in a Python sense as @phd comments) to use as a attribute name.

What does "branch" here mean?

The name you give in your question does not seem to have any "illegal characters" in it: git log feature-generate-events should work just fine. Can you give more details about your issue ? What characters seem to give you static / what git commands do you type in your shell ?

Your “e.g.” is legal as already mentioned. Run git check-ref-format on the branch name to make sure that it is legal.

@Guildenstern In Git sense the branch'es name is legal, no problem. It's illegal in Python sense, illegal as an attribute name.

https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.util.IterableList

Try
getattr(repo.heads, 'feature-generate-events')

